# Why does saturation occur when the populations of the spin-up and spin-down energy levels are equal?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I'm learning about NMR spectroscopy and I don't understand why saturation occurs when the populations of the higher and lower energy levels of spin are equal. Why wouldn't energy continue to be absorbed until all the spins are in the higher energy level - why is no more energy absorbed once equal numbers are in both energy levels?